# Similarity in python(3+)

Tags: python

I have created a movie recommendation system in python and now I am trying to 
find the Manhattan Distance between two users.

So, I have upload from 2 files the necessary information(User_ids,movie_title and ratings), the code is below:

```
def LoadTheData():
    movies={}
    user_pref={}
    for line in open('u.item'):
        (movies_id, movie_title) = line.split('|')[0:2]
        movies[movies_id] = movie_title

    for line in open('u.data'):
        (user_id, movie_id, rating) = line.split('\t')[0:3]
        user_pref.setdefault(user_id,{})
        user_pref[user_id][movies[movie_id] ] = float(rating)
    return user_pref
User_preference=LoadTheData()
print(User_preference)
```

So, I have created the User_preference dictionary which contains users_ids, movies and ratings from the above 2 files.

```
User_preference = {'196': {'Kolya (1996)': 3.0, 'Mrs. Doubtfire (1993)': 
4.0, "Muriel's Wedding (1994)": 4.0, 'Shall We Dance? (1996)': 3.0, 'Stand 
by Me (1986)': 5.0,
```

And now i would like to calculate the Manhattan difference between 2 users and my formula is:

```
def manhattan_distance(User_preference,user1,user2):

    for user1, user2 in User_preference(user1, user2):

        return sqrt(sum(pow(user1-user2,2)))
print(manhattan_distance(User_preference,'100','206'))
```

But, I am getting an error. Does someone know how should I write it?

The error is ' 'dict' object is not callable in the print statement.

Comment: *What* error? There's not enough code for us to guess what error you might be getting.

Comment: The 'dict' object is not callable

Comment: Well, it's not. What do you expect `user_preference(user1, user2)` to do? (I'm assuming the differences in capitalization are typos in the question.)

Comment: Assuming `user1` is supposed to be `user_preference['100']` (and likewise for `user2`), you also can't subtract a `dict` from another.

Comment: But I did it for the euclidean similarity

Comment: Do you have a function called `user_preference` that you aren't showing? I'm just guessing, because it's not obvious what `user1` and `user2` are supposed to be.

Comment: I am so sorry, I updated the post, you are able to see it. User1 suppose to be an input user, for example '196' and user2  '206' in order to find the Manhattan distance

Comment: No, I don't see it. I see two identifiers, `User_preference` and `user_preference`. If that's a capitalization error in the question, then no, you can't use a `dict` like it is a function. If it is not a capitalization error, there is no definition of a function named `user_preference` in this question.

Comment: You misspelled “preference” where you create the dictionary. Maybe that’s what causing the error?

Comment: Actually no, the error isn't the capitalization of User_preference. No, I fixed it.

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 2):

Might have to do with those parantheses not being closed on the second to last line

```
def manhattan_distance(User_preference,user1,user2):

    for user1, user2 in user_preference(user1, user2):

        return sqrt(sum(pow(user1-user2,2))) #<---here 
print(manhattan_distance(User_preference,'100','206'))
```

Aside from that parantheses `()` indicate a call to a function. but `user_preference` is a `dict` object, which you cannot call as such. if you want to reference a value in the dictionary by it's key you should use square brackets `[]` instead. Again though, if you do not provide a working example of what you're trying to do, it's really difficult to see where the issue is.

At this point it's likely to be a design choice or a lack of understanding on your part regarding the use of dictionaries.

Comment: you were right,but know i have one more.
The 'dict' object is not callable

Comment: i'm sorry but without more code to go on there's just no way to know

Comment: give a sec to update it. I updated it. Actualy I have a dictionary, with user_ids, movies_titles and ratings and I'ld like to use Manhattan distance to find the difference between 2 users

Comment: Let me give you all the information of my exercise.